# R: split string vector by delimiter and rearrange

Tags: r, stringi

I have string vector that needs to be split and rearranged in a matrix in a certain way. I know how to do split/simple rearrange, but lost how my to rearrange how I want:

```
library(stringi)

vec = c("b;a;c","a;c","c;b")
q = stri_split_fixed(vec, ";", simplify = TRUE,fill=T)
View(q)

V1  V2  V3
b   a   c
a   c    
c   b
```

Desired output

```
V1  V2  V3
a   b   c
a       c 
    b   c
```

Thank you!
EDIT:

Letters above are for simplicity. Real options are (not exhaustive list): `D-Amazon Marketplace`, `U-Amazon`, `D-Amazon`, `U-Jet`, etc. Starts with `U` and `D` only, though.

Order - alphabetical but grouped by retailer. If too complicated - no order is OK

Comment: Can you always assume that the first row will contain all the factors/letters?

Comment: No. Arbitrary length

Comment: Do you know how many total options there are? Alternatively, does the order matter or does it just need to group characters that are the same in the same column?

Comment: I think you'll need a more complete example then, what happens if the first row is `b, a, c, _, d`? Does `d` move over?

Comment: I massage data first so there can be alpha characters

Comment: Edited. No prior knowledge of options

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This solution generates a boolean matrix with each vector as a row, and each possible character as a column.

```
possible_options = c('a', 'b', 'c')
result <- sapply(possible_options, function(x) apply(q, 1, function(y) x %in% y))
result
         a     b    c
[1,]  TRUE  TRUE TRUE
[2,]  TRUE FALSE TRUE
[3,] FALSE  TRUE TRUE
```

This solution requires a list of all the options. If you don't have that, you can either make a list of all possible options (for example all alphanumeric characters) and then remove blank rows:

```
result <- sapply(c(letters, LETTERS), function(x) apply(q, 1, function(y) x %in% y))
result <- result[, colSums(result) > 0]
result
         a     b    c
[1,]  TRUE  TRUE TRUE
[2,]  TRUE FALSE TRUE
[3,] FALSE  TRUE TRUE
```

Or extract them from the result of `q`

```
opts <- as.character(unique(unlist(q)))
opts <- opts[sort.list(opts[opts != ''])]
result <- sapply(opts , function(x) apply(q, 1, function(y) x %in% y))
result
         a     b    c
[1,]  TRUE  TRUE TRUE
[2,]  TRUE FALSE TRUE
[3,] FALSE  TRUE TRUE
```